# Intellij differences between adding dependencies to the pom.xml and Project Structure ->Libraries

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I must say that I am a bit confused. I was struggling with as I saw common problem with error 406 for returning JSON object from Spring MVC. Normally I used Project Structure ->Libraries to add new dependencies like in that case jackson-mapper-asl, but only after I included it manually in the pom.xml it worked fine.

My question is: Is it common problem or maybe my IDEA is somehow wrongly configured?

Comment: How do you intend to build your project with Maven if the pom.xml doesn't reference the appropriate libraries? Maven won't read the configuration files of IntelliJ. And your coworkers using Eclipse won't be happy either.

Comment: so the Libraries added to the Intellij are not automatically updating pom.xml and I should do that by myself?

Comment: Yes. The pom.xml is the descriptor of your project. IntelliJ reads it and configures its project from what it finds inside.